# Jasper report left edge is cut when printing in landscape

Tags: java

I am using netbeans 8.0 with JasperReport, my problem is that when I  set the report to print in landscape the preview is fine, but when I print it the left edge of the paper it cut, it does not show. I have changed the margins to all possible values and nothing. I have searched in the web with  almost no information about it, I really would appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

jm

Here is the file, thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="null" columnDirection="RTL" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="832" leftMargin="5" rightMargin="5" topMargin="5" bottomMargin="5" uuid="bda40859-2239-4b1a-bca9-5a0a0f4ec383">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="2.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="Title" forecolor="#FFFFFF" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Bold"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#CCCCCC" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="18" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="14" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0EFEF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select *
from paises]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="codpais" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="descripcion" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="activo" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="precious" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="iniciales" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="6" y="5" width="41" height="10" forecolor="#FF0000" uuid="45fa0c62-17a4-4e47-92c5-929e3f846908"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[codpais]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="47" y="5" width="165" height="10" forecolor="#FF0000" uuid="773cac6d-1370-426c-8f5a-a9531463cbef"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[descripcion]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="225" y="5" width="64" height="10" forecolor="#FF0000" uuid="3cee84e3-a894-4398-b843-711125d30f78"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[activo]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="23"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="18" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="7" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Need to look at the design.

Comment: I have looked and changed all options, please be more specific.

Comment: Even with the report wizard, the left edge is cut!

Comment: Need to see you jrxml file.

Comment: There is the jrxml file. thanks.

Comment: The design looks fine. Have you checked the print from other printers?